# putting local tabBar on the global tabBar (I have a global tabBarController)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have put one global tabBarController in iphone app that I have been working on.
But in one of my screen I needed to put the local tabBar which is different from the global tabBarController.

I have done it in two ways: 
1) Hiding the global tabBar by self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = yes; and putting local tabBar in place of it in the view. But the frame of tabBar is showing blank white.
2) Tried by adding the local tabBar as subview of global tabBar which worked but after screen is unloaded its not removing the local tabBar though applying [localTabBar removeFromSuperView];

Thanks in advance..

```
Global tabBarController:
tabBarController          = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray    arrayWithObjects:ActivityTabnav,nav2,privateChatnav,ExploreTabnav,nav3,tempTabnav, nil];
```

localtabBar is a tabBar on view xib of viewController.
in vIewDidLoad >

```
 UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
 [window addSubview:self.tabBar];
```

in vIewDidUnLoad >

```
[self.tabBar removeFromSuperview];
```

Previously I tried to add self.tabBar to self.tabBarController.tabBar as a subView which persisted the local self.tabBar in other screens.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way I've found to do this is to set the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property of your view controller, then place it inside a `UINavigationController` (hiding the navigiationBar if you don't need it). This will hide the `UITabBarController's` `UITabBar` without leaving a white space.

You'd then put the local `UITabBar` directly into the `UIViewController's` view;

Another possibility would be to hide the `UITabBarController's` `UITabBar`, then add the local `UITabBar` to as a subview of `UITabBarController's` view. Of course you'd have to remove from superview when needed.

Comment: I am afraid I did that. setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property worked but after the screen is unloaded localTabBar is persister though its being removed from superview. I have done setting the localtabBar as a subview of global tabBar and tabBarController View as well..

Comment: Hey Hi,Thank you all.. in initialize function of viewController setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed of the global tabBar did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add TabBar on Window. But be sure that you handle is correctly. You can add it on window by taking the Current Window object and then add TabBar onto it... as below...

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview:tabbar];
```

this could be one option but handle it carefully...

Comment: It adds the tabBar but when the screen is unloaded (i.e. viedDidUnload) [tabBar removeFromSuperview] isn't removing it. This local view is getting persisted onto other screens. Thanks...